# Ansible-vault not being passed to playbook correctly

Tags: ansible

I am trying to use ansible and ansible-vault to provision users. This is my current directory structure:

```
|-- ansible-test.out
|-- group_vars
|-- inventory
|-- roles
|   |-- bsd_sudoers
|   |   |-- tasks
|   |   |-- templates
|   |   |   `-- cde-admins
|   |   `-- vars
|   `-- bsd_users
|       |-- files
|       |-- tasks
|       |   `-- main.yml
|       |-- templates
|       `-- vars
|           `-- all.yml
|-- site.retry
|-- site.yml
`-- vars
    `-- all.yml
```

This is what I have for my playbook so far:

```
---
- name: Creating Users
  user:
    name: "{{ item.name }}"
    system : "{{ item.sudoer }}"
    shell: /bin/bash
    password: "{{ item.password }}"
    uid: "{{ item.uid }}"
    home: "{{ item.home }}"
  with_items: users
```

Here is a sample of what I have in ansible vault:

```
---
   vars:
     users:
       - name: 'foo'
         home: '/home/foo'
         key: 'ssh-rsa ....'
         password: '!!'
         bash: '/bin/bash'
         sudoer: yes
         uid: "2049"
         guid: '2049'
         group: admin
```

When I run the playbook, this error message is always generated:

```
fatal: [ansible-test]: FAILED! => {"failed": true, "msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'ansible.utils.unsafe_proxy.AnsibleUnsafeText object' has no attribute 'uid'\n\nThe error appears to have been in '/Users/ansible/playbooks/roles/bsd_users/tasks/main.yml': line 2, column 3, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n---\n- name: Creating Users\n  ^ here\n\nexception type: <class 'ansible.errors.AnsibleUndefinedVariable'>\nexception: 'ansible.utils.unsafe_proxy.AnsibleUnsafeText object' has no attribute 'uid'"}
    to retry, use: --limit @/Users/ansible/playbooks/site.retry
```

Why is this always happening? I was under the impression that Ansible would naturally pass the encrypted variables to my playbook but this does not seem to be the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First:

`with_items: users` should be `with_items: "{{ users }}"`.
[Bare variables](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40382545/2795592) are not supported any more.

Second:

There's no need to define top-level `vars` dict in vaulted files, use:

```
---
users:
  - name: foo
    home: /home/foo
  - name: bar
    home: /home/bar
```

Comment: I will give that a whirl

Comment: Now I get users is not defined

Comment: Where is your vaulted vars file located?

Comment: vars/all.yml -- it is outside of roles

Comment: You should manually include it as `-e @vars/all.yml` or with `vars_files` inside playbook or place `all.yml` into `group_vars`.

Comment: Moving it to group_vars generates this: ERROR! Attempting to decrypt but no vault secrets found

Comment: Sorry, I'm not an interactive debugger :-/ Please pay attention to error messages.

Comment: Well i did, sorry to hammer down these error messages, I tried looking this up already and couldnt find anything on it. This is why it brought me here

Answer (score 4):

As Konstantin mentioned before, you need to include the variable file either as `-e @vars/all.yml` via the command line, or by adding `vars_files` into the playbook. You can also add the `all.yml` file into the `group_vars` directory, and it will be picked up automatically.

Regarding the second error message you are receiving, starting with Ansible 2.4 the recommended way of providing the password at the command line is by using `--vault-id`. This can be anything from a path to the id file, to `@prompt` for Ansible to prompt you for a password, or even the path to a script that returns the password.

Prior to Ansible 2.4, you need to use `--ask-vault-pass` or `--vault-password-file`.

You can also add a variable in `ansible.cfg` named `vault_password_file`, where you can define the location of the vault password file (for example `vault_password_file = /path/to/.vault_password_file`), so you don't need to specify it every time you run `ansible-playbook`. Starting with Ansible 1.7, this path can also point to a script that returns the password as stdout.

If this helps answer your question, I would appreciate it if you could mark it as the accepted answer.